# How do I write a python function that returns a dictionary

Tags: python

I have written the following

```
def convert(col):
    value = 0
    value = value + 1
    res_dct = {col[i]:value for i in range(0, len(col))}
    return res_dct
```

right now when I pass in the list `['one', 'two', 'three']`, it returns `{'one':1, 'two':1, 'three':1}`

I would like it to return `{'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}`

Answer (score 2):

You can do so:

```
def convert(col):
    res_dct = {col[i]:i+1 for i in range(0, len(col))}
    return res_dct

convert(['one', 'two', 'three'])
#returns {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

You should know that the numbers have nothing to do with the actual values. In other words, if the input list was `['two', 'three', 'one']`, the result will be `{'two': 1, 'three': 2, 'one': 3}`.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfect for a list. What if I wanted to pass in column of a data frame instead and have the function return each value as key and a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` doesn't changed each part of the loop, use `i` instead which is already incrementing:

```
def convert(col):
    res_dct = {col[i]:(i+1) for i in range(0, len(col))}
    return res_dct
```